# What is default response format of Soap based web service, WCF Service and WEBAPI?

Tags: web-services, wcf, asp.net-web-api, soap

What is the default Response format of SOAP Based service ,WCF service and WEBAPI service?

Comment: This question is a little meaningless in its current form. What do you mean by *default*?

Comment: I mean response format is xml,json or atom?

Comment: SOAP: XML, WCF Service: Windows binary/XML/JSON/ActiveX binary, WEBAPI: JSON/XML

Comment: Thanks @tomredfern but is there any default format I mean if we are not supplying Responseformat=Responseformat.XML then what is the default one if you can tell me it would be great